# Android - Can't draw same size square on all devices

Tags: java, android

I have an application running on android on which I have to draw a grid. I would like the cells of the grid to be of the same size on all devices, and I've found this method to do that:

```
float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float SIZE =  DESIRED_DP_VALUE * scale + 0.5f;
```

DESIRED_DP_VALUE is a value I set for the cells dimension.
I've tried the app on two smartphones and a tablet: the tablet and one of the smartphones have the cells of the same size, while the other smartphone doesn't.

This is the method I use to draw the grid:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    int count=0;

    while(count<=row){
        float coordinate=count*SIZE;
        canvas.drawLine(coordinate,0,coordinate,column*SIZE,whitePaint);
        count++;
    }

    count=0;

    while(count<=column){
        float coordinate=count*SIZE;
        canvas.drawLine(0,coordinate,row*SIZE,coordinate,whitePaint);
        count++;
    } 
}
```

The grid is draw correctly on each device.
Where could the problem be?

Comment: Your desired DP value is probably what it is named - an xy dp value. DPs display differently on different screen sizes (they are density pixels and some devices have different screen DPs). This means you should support multiple device screens, ussually done in XMLs. In your case, I would try to get the information about the devices screen DP and make a switch statement to see in which category it falls in. And then adjust the "Desire DP value" for those screens.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing some concepts.
The size in pixels is that, how many dots are counting per with or height.
Every device has its own screen size measured in inches and the amount of pixels or dots able to draw in width and height.
The relationship between dimension and pixels is the density.
So, what do you want to do?
Draw an square which shows the same physical size on the screen or a square with the same amount of pixels?
If you want to draw based on inches, take it that way.
For drawing an one inch square, for a device with a density of 300 pixels per inch you need 300 pixels.
If the device is 150 pixels per inch, you must draw a 150 pixels square.
So, you need to keep fixed the size in inches, not the desired DP.

Comment: I would like to draw based on inches, so what do I have to change in my formula?

Comment: Lets say your target size is 5 inches:

float desiredWidth = 5.0f;
float desiredHeight = 5.0f;

You can get your device capabilities and the dpi so:

float deviceXdpi = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi;
float deviceYdpi = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().ydpi;

And the ammount of pixel required:

float pixelsWidthrequired = desiredWidth * deviceXdpi;
float pixelsHeightrequired = desiredHeight * deviceYdpi;

So, being drawLine uses pixels, you should be able to draw based on the given size

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but I've tried your method and still doesn't work. I did this:
`float deviceXDpi = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi;`
`SIZE = deviceXDpi*desiredWidth;`
Then I use drawline the way I posted in the question. The number of rows and columns that have be drawn is calculated this way:
`width = getWidth();`
`row = (int) (width /SIZE)`
Same for the columns, but of course with getHeight. Wonder if the problem is here ...

Comment: I checked the densities of the two devices, and they are the same. That means that the value returned by the formula is the same, so I don't understand why it keeps drawing different size cells